# Redirect direct image urls to image post or attachment page?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, .htaccess

New :
I have a wallpaper website and I recently checked the server log of the files accessed and I saw that I am getting lots of traffic on the image files rather than the page of the website.

So I want to do is redirect example.com/sample-image.jpg to example.com/sample-image.html

I am using WordPress CMS and I tried one .htaccess code but it redirects all the images to the homepage of website :(

OLD:

When a user attempts to load an image directly into the browser (for example from Google Images), the browser normally opens just the bare image.

I'm trying to address the following situation:

1) User is browsing Google Images and finds an image. 2) Google Images offers the user to open the website where the image was found or just open the original image. 3) The user chooses the latter, therefore the ball is now on the webserver where the image is hosted. 4) htaccess detects a human operated browser trying to access directly to an image in /uploads/ folder. 5) htaccess redirects the user to single-attachment.php or post in which image include or attached.

Answer (score 1):

Images/media it is post type. Try `get_permalink($id_of_attachment);` If you have url of image you can get id too. Example by `get_post_thumbnail_id();`

Comment: thanks for help , but im new this so can you provide some reference how to do this. thanks a lot